# XMLPullParser black diamond question marks with certain characters

Tags: android, xml, character-encoding, xmlpullparser

I'm making an android app, that needs to fetch and parse XML. The class for that was made following the instructions from here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_rss_reader.htm and the fetcher method looks like this:

```
public void fetchXML() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);


                // Starts the query
                conn.connect();
                InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

                xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                xmlFactoryObject.setValidating(false);
                xmlFactoryObject.setFeature(Xml.FEATURE_RELAXED, true);
                xmlFactoryObject.setNamespaceAware(true);

                XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
                //myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                myparser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));

                parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                stream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Parser looks like the one in tutorial, with my parsing logic in it.

As you can see from

```
 myparser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
```

I'm using UTF-8 charset. Now when I use ***getText() method in my parser for example on the word 'Jõhvi', the logcat output is 'J�hvi'***. It's the same for other characters of my native language, Estonian, that aren't in English alphabet. I need to use this string as a key and in the user interface, so this isn't acceptable. I'm thinking it's a charset problem, but there is no info at the XML site I'm pulling this from and using

```
conn.getContentEncoding()
```

returns *null* so I'm in the dark here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content encoding and character encoding are not the same thing.

Content encoding refers to compression such as gzip.  Since `getContentEncoding()` is null, that tells you there's no compression.

You should be looking at `conn.getContentType()`, because the character encoding can usually be found in the `content-type` response header.

`conn.getContentType()` might return something like:

`text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1`

so you will have to do some parsing.  Look for the character set name after "charset=" but be prepared for the case where the mime type is specified but the charset is not.

Comment: Thank you! While `conn.getContentType()` only returned`text/xml`, I used your suggested encoding and it worked. I also googled a bit and found, that ISO-8859-4 is the 'official Estonian' encoding, which also worked.